# Correct Git user when pushing as root via SSH

Tags: ssh, gitlab, root

We have multiple users using servers as root via SSH. Current 'problem' is not seeing the correct user when a change is pushed to GitLab.

Is there a solution for this, besides using 'sudo' from their own user when committing?

Comment: Why is anyone using `root` with Git?

Comment: Hi @chepner. This is just the way the environment I am currently working in is set up. I realise that committing this way with multiple users is not the ideal situation. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Consider pushing to change that. There should be a *reason* for running anything as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a wrapper script for the git command: **[`Vonc/gitw`](https://github.com/VonC/gitw)**

```
alias git='gitshellenv=$- ~/gits/gitw.sh'
```

That script will check if the command is called in an interractive session of not:

```
if [[ ${gitshellenv} != *i* ]]; then
    commmand git  "$@"
    exit $?
fi
```

That means any `git` command done in a script would still called `git` as usual, but any command done in the *interactive* shell manually would go on.

By "go on", I mean the wrapper would then check if `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` is set or not.
If not, it calls a small program which ash the user to enter their name/email, and it will set `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME/EMAIL` accordingly, before calling the `git` command.

It will also record that name/email in `/tmp/file` associated with the current user session, in order to *not* ask again during the current session.
It records also the `SSH_CLIENT` IP address: if the user always comes from that IP, at their next session, their name can be reused.

Comment: Looks amazing! Any chance you could share the wrapper script?

Comment: @Jsack7 I will make it open-source, but for now, it is a Go program made for my company. I need to cleanup the code from what is specific to said company.

Comment: I have found a workaround while learning and experimenting with Bash. So if you're very busy, don't free up time to make it open-source unless you already planned on doing so. Thanks for your input and help; much appreciated.

Comment: @Jsack7 No problem. I will release a first version this w-end. That might help others.

Comment: @Jsack7 the wrapper is now public: https://github.com/VonC/gitw